# How to check current domain and redirect other domains to avoid frameset?

Tags: javascript, php, iframe, frameset, frameset-iframe

Is it any way to check current domain if it's set to **example.com** then page won't be redirected and if URL is not set to current domain then page will be redirected to example.com?

Actually I want to check if other domains are using **FRAMESET** to my website then those websites will be redirected to my website.

I found this following JavaScript code:

```
if ( window.self !== window.top ) {
window.top.location.href=window.location.href;
}
```

but there is a problem here, some of my pages will be redirected to **Page not found!** maybe because I'm using google iframe.

*

- However this question is look like duplicated, but the main issue in
  this question is about when we are using iframe in our website and if
  we will use above JavaScript line then our website will be
  redirected too, but I'm going to avoid other domains to use FRAMESET to
  my website.
  -

> Is it possible to avoid FRAMESET for other domains while we are using google
>   iframe too (for example)?

I highly appreciate your help

Comment: confused but i think your asking how to use iframes, but stop people iframing your site?

Comment: Stop people iframing to my website. how to do it ?

Comment: Could you check the window.top in your code to see if it is your i frames window as well? if( !(window.top === window)) //if true here, there is a parent window above you. I think that's the syntax but doing it on the fly

Comment: Yes right, finally I found a solution, because I'm using google iframe that's why I got this problem, I changed iframe to embed then the problem solved.